# Remove Some Character From Records Using SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am having question mark symbol(?) in between first name and last name of Customers in some records, I want to replace all "?" with a space.

```
UPDATE Customers
//What to write here?
WHERE Name LIKE '%?%';
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
UPDATE customers set name= replace(name,'?', ' ') WHERE Name LIKE '%?%';
```

(inverted parameters in replace)